# how to order random values by hashcode in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I have a simple class that fills in a simple hashmap I want to order values by hashcode how to do that?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

    public class Ch11Ex18 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Random rand = new Random(47);
            Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
              // Produce a number between 0 and 20:
              int r = rand.nextInt(20);
              Integer freq = m.get(r);
              m.put(r, freq == null ? 1 : freq + 1);

            }
            System.out.println(m);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Order the values where? Just printing them? Get the keys, sort them, iterate over them, and dump the values.

Comment: proly export to list and make a comparator which uses hashCode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't: `HashMap` is inherently unordered.

You could use `TreeMap` with a custom comparator, but then you should be aware that if you use unequal objects with the same hash code, only one of them will end up in the map... and even so this would order by the *keys* rather than the values.

You could create an `ArrayList<Integer>` containing a copy of the values, and sort *that* - but then you won't have the keys.

You could create an `ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>` containing a copy of the *entries*, and sort that... but really, what's the point?

Fundamentally, this is an odd thing to do - hash codes should *not* be used like this, basically. They're not unique, shouldn't be viewed as a source of randomness, etc. Whatever the bigger picture is here, there's pretty much bound to be a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

A TreeMap sorts by key.

```
Map yourMap= new HashMap();
// Enter values
Map sortedMap = new TreeMap(yourMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, since [`Integer.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29) is equal to the actual number, you can just plug your mappings into a `TreeMap`, and they will be sorted accordingly.

Comment: +1 This answer is shorter and more complete than mine (now deleted) was.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration order of a HashMap is the natural ordering of the hash codes of the keys (because the hash value determines the bucket and the buckets are iterated over sequentially), so you could just iterate over `map.keySet()`. For the key type Integer, the hash code is equal to the actual value of the Integer.